# Trying to create a jQuery image rotator but can only get the first half of it to work

Tags: jquery, css, image, rotation

I'm trying to create an image rotator where one image will fade into the next and so on until it loops back to the first image. I got the first two images to work correctly but the remaining 3 don't fade correctly. They just jump into view.

I know I still need to account for the reaching the end of the rotation. I haven't taken care of that yet because I'm just trying to get the first round of rotation to work.

What am I missing to get this to work correctly?

My HTML:

```
    <div id="imageRotator">
    <div id="image01" class="current">
        <img src="images/imageRotate01.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="image02" class="next">
        <img src="images/imageRotate02.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="image03" class="hidden">
        <img src="images/imageRotate03.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="image04" class="hidden">
        <img src="images/imageRotate04.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="image05" class="hidden">
        <img src="images/imageRotate05.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#imageRotator div {
    position: absolute;
}

.current {
    z-index: 1;
}

.next {
    z-index: 0;
}

.hidden {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var firstImage = $('#image01');
    var currentImage, nextImage;

    setInterval(rotateImages, 2000);

    function rotateImages() {
        currentImage = $('div.current');
        nextImage = $('div.next');

        //the first image fades away
        currentImage.animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, function() {
            currentImage.removeClass('current');    
        });

        //bring the second image into view
        nextImage.animate({opacity: 1}, 2000, function() {

            //make the new image the current image
            nextImage.removeClass('next').addClass('current');

            //the next image in the rotation becomes the 'next' image
            nextImage.next().addClass('next').removeClass('hidden');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you purposely trying to write a script from scratch? Why not use one of the tools already developed and tested, like CarouFredSel? This is a really great script for simple rotations and is really easy to implement. It even has a handy-dandy wizard for customizing your functions. http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/configuration-robot.php

Comment: The first thing I'd say is to avoid using `setInterval`, because it has some quirks that can cause it to act strangely if you have any other code that blocks it from running (which is pretty common). Better to use a self-repeating `setTimeout` instead. More info here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts

Comment: Yes I'm trying to make my own as a learning experience but I got stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set a zero `opacity` by default so there is no animation for `opacity` for the elements after the first. Try setting it to 0 to all the elements but the first and see what happens.

```
#imageRotator div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    background:red;
    opacity: 0;
}
#imageRotator div:first-child{
        opacity:1;
}
.current {
    z-index: 1;
}

.next {
    z-index: 0;
}

.hidden {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/N3gXd/

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I'm making this from scratch so I can become as quick as you in figuring out these problems.